# Received all indexes of elements greater than x in ndarray of size n*n python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, logical-operators

I have a `ndarray` of size n*n (200,200).

I want to find all the indexes of the values that greater then 0 and then change them to 1.

I try to do something like that and I received exception.

```
toggleOn_index = [x for x in  net if x>0]
net[toggleOn_index]=1
```

What is the most efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

If I start with some array `a` as follows

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(5, 5) - 0.5
>>> a
array([[ 0.24116601, -0.23917393,  0.46607471,  0.08560729,  0.33878893],
       [ 0.24681769, -0.01693847,  0.22579766, -0.38570793, -0.2075437 ],
       [-0.19602781, -0.46108244, -0.40341244,  0.42579818,  0.4655471 ],
       [-0.14669409,  0.36171014, -0.36496558, -0.30983999, -0.06633584],
       [-0.09159042,  0.23346471,  0.37680536, -0.09281205, -0.04552193]])
```

I can assign to all the elements that are greater than `0` using

```
>>> a[a > 0] = 1
>>> a
array([[ 1.        , -0.23917393,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        , -0.01693847,  1.        , -0.38570793, -0.2075437 ],
       [-0.19602781, -0.46108244, -0.40341244,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [-0.14669409,  1.        , -0.36496558, -0.30983999, -0.06633584],
       [-0.09159042,  1.        ,  1.        , -0.09281205, -0.04552193]])
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your approach is that `x>0` will return a 1D boolean array:

```
import numpy as np

net = np.random.random((2, 5))

for i in net:
    print(i > 0)
# [ True  True  True  True  True]
# [ True  True  True  True  True]
```

But you can't evaluate these arrays with an `if`:

```
if np.array([True, True, True, True, True]):
    pass
```

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

---

As already mentioned NumPy supports element-wise operations, so you could simply use:

```
net[net > 0] = 1
```

In case you want a new array with the values replaced you can use the three-argument form of [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
newnet = np.where(net > 0, 1, net)
```

To literally get the indices you can use the one-argument form of `np.where`:

```
indices = np.where(net > 0)
net[indices] = 1               # it can also be used to set the elements to 1.
```